# Hash routing Navigation is not working - react router redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new in React js and i am using hash routing for my project, i have a login page and dashboard.. when i click the login button i should redirect to dashboard.

currently, when i click login button, url is chaning from 'http://localhost:8080/#/login' to http://localhost:8080/#/dashboard - but page is not rendering.. :(

this is the code i am using to push - 
    store.dispatch(push('#/dashboard'));

Used this link to configure - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux

```
const history = createHistory();
const middleware = routerMiddleware(history);  
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();    //saga


export const store = createStore(combineReducers({ login: L_reducer, router: routerReducer }),applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware,middleware));
//no error

sagaMiddleware.run(watcherSaga);

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
  <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" component={Login}/>
      <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" component={Register}/>
      <Route path="/" name="Home" component={Full}/>
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
  </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>

), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Well, you don't have a route matching `/dashboard` so it's normal nothing renders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After so many work around its worked when i changed the code like this...

```
const history = createHashHistory();
const middleware = routerMiddleware(history);   
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();    //saga


export const store = createStore(combineReducers({ login: reducer, router: routerReducer }),applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware,middleware));
//no error

sagaMiddleware.run(watcherSaga);

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
 <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
   <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" component={Login}/>
     <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" component={Register}/>
     <Route path="/" name="Home" component={Full}/>
   </Switch>
 </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>

), document.getElementById('root'));
```